# Find point on the perimeter of a rectangle in Objective-C (Sprite Kit)

Tags: objective-c, sprite, rectangles

I want to move an object from a random point just outside of the view in a Sprite Kit game.

The logical way of doing this would be to create a rectangle 100px (example) bigger than the view, and pick a random point on it's perimeter. Unfortunately, I don't know an easy way to do this.

How can I easily create a random point on the perimeter of a rectangle (which is slightly bigger than my view)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This should do what you want:

```
- (CGPoint)randomPointOutsideRect:(CGRect)rect withOffset:(CGFloat)offset {
    NSUInteger random = arc4random_uniform(4);
    UIRectEdge edge = 1 << random; // UIRectEdge enum values are defined with bit shifting

    CGPoint randomPoint = CGPointZero;
    if (edge == UIRectEdgeTop || edge == UIRectEdgeBottom) {
        randomPoint.x = arc4random_uniform(CGRectGetWidth(rect)) + CGRectGetMinX(rect);
        if (edge == UIRectEdgeTop) {
            randomPoint.y = CGRectGetMinY(rect) - offset;
        }
        else {
            randomPoint.y = CGRectGetMaxY(rect) + offset;
        }
    }
    else if (edge == UIRectEdgeLeft || edge == UIRectEdgeRight) {
        randomPoint.y = arc4random_uniform(CGRectGetHeight(rect)) + CGRectGetMinY(rect);
        if (edge == UIRectEdgeLeft) {
            randomPoint.x = CGRectGetMinX(rect) - offset;
        }
        else {
            randomPoint.x = CGRectGetMaxX(rect) + offset;
        }
    }

    return randomPoint;
}
```

This should be fairly straightforward, let me know if there's something unclear.
Basically, we pick one edge at random, then "fix" one axis and pick a random value on the other (within the width/height boundaries).

`arc4random_uniform` gives us only integers, but that's fine because floating point values in frames are bad when displaying stuff on screen.

There is probably a shorter way to write this; feel free to edit to improve, everyone.

---

**Original answer**

> How can I easily create a point 100 pixels away from the edge of my view?

With [`CGRectOffset()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH1g-F17162).

Assuming you want a `CGPoint` 100pt "higher" (ie. with a lower `y`) than your view, do:

```
CGRect viewFrame = // lets say for this example that your frame is at {{20, 40}, {300, 600}}
CGRect offsetFrame = CGRectOffset(viewFrame, 0, -100);
CGPoint offsetPoint = offsetFrame.origin
// offsetPoint = {20, -60}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. What I'm looking for is a random point on the view's perimeter, with a slight offset in the direction of the side it's on (e.g. if the point is on the top of the rectangle, move it up by 100 pixels). I'll be sure to clarify. Thanks again!